# Remove unallocated space on VHD

Tags: windows-xp, vhd

I just moved from XP to Windows 7. I wanted to virtualize my XP machine, so I copied the data to VHD and tried to boot from it. Well my drive was 149gb so I split them into 2 vhd files of their drives. I was able to shrink the C drive. But I can't do it to the E (or H in the screenshot)

I need to figure out how to remove the unallocated space or copy the partition to a new drive.

[image]

Comment: Their are tools for VHD files that do exactly this.  A google search would find them.

Comment: I googled it already. I downloaded VHD resizer. But it wont resize it to a disk smaller then 149gb. It worked for my C drive, but maybe because it's located at the end of the partition, it doesn't like it??